# Python Multiprocessing vs Separate Script

Tags: python, pyqt, multiprocessing

I am running a pyqt app that has various processes (4) running in Windows. I have a UI, video capture, video display, and machine learning (inferencing) processes.

What I notice is, when I have all the processes running at the same time, the machine learning inference time doubles in time from when I run the same process alone which is undesirable. Also if I run the other 3 processes and start up an entirely new python script running just the machine learning process, the machine learning inferencing time does not suffer even a single millisecond. So it's in my best interest to have two python scripts running, unless of course I am doing something wrong.

Just in terms of general rule of thumb, is this behavior normal or is it likely I am implementing my pyqt app incorrectly with the multiprocessing library?

Comment: With "processes" do you mean actual *separate* scripts spawned as actual different programs, or using the multiprocessing module? Can you please be more specific and add more details about the structure of your program, including what each part does and how it interacts with the others?

Comment: By processes I meant that I am using the multiprocessing library to spawn 4 processes under the same app. When running all 4 multiprocesses in the same app, the machine learning inferencing time suffers. If I run the machine learning in a completely separate python script, while the app is running with the other 3 multiprocesses, the machine learning inferencing is fast

Comment: Sorry but that's insufficient to understand the issue, so please [edit] your post and either explain **with sufficient details** how your program works, or you provide a proper [mre].